# I have a model with a field and I would like a view to order the items in a specific order based on the value for the field

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have an Item model for menu items which can be a daily special. If they are a daily special I would like them to be ordered by day of the week starting with Monday. I believe the view should be doing the sorting.

Here is my models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (('Sandwich', 'Sandwich'), ('Salad', 'Salad'), ('Slider', 'Slider'), ('Side', 'Side'), ('Drink', 'Drink'))
    DAYS = ((0,'Monday'), (1,'Tuesday'), (2,'Wednesday'), (3,'Thursday'), (4,'Friday'), (5,'Saturday'), (6,'Sunday'))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=DAYS, unique=True, blank=True)

    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False),
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def specials(request):
    # days = (('Monday'), ('Tuesday'), ('Wednesday'), ('Thursday'), ('Friday'), ('Saturday'), ('Sunday'))
    specials_list = Item.objects.filter(special = True)
    # specials_list = sorted(specials_list, key=days)  //Trying to sort the list by days of the week
    context = {
        'specials_list': specials_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'menu/specials.html', context)
```

I feel like I am really close here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) lets you use the `order_by` method to order your resulting query set.

So inside your view, you could do:

```
specials_list = Item.objects.filter(special = True).order_by('day')
```

If you need descending order, you can replace `.order_by('day')` with `.order_by('-day')`.

Comment: D'oh, forgot the quotes around day when I was tinkering. Thank you!